# Python -- execution shell commands using a designated shells

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, tcsh

so I know python can execute shell commands using subprocess.call()

But I normally use tcsh, and I have a .tcshrc that loads a lot of environmental variables to make my shell comfortable.

How do I make my subprocess.call() realize that -- execute my commands in tcsh, load my .tcshrc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly invoke tcsh to execute the respective cmds, like this (replace `env` with your specific cmd arg list:

```
~/> cat tst.py
#!/usr/bin/python -u
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/tcsh', '-c', 'env'])
~/> ./tst.py | grep ^DISPLAY
DISPLAY=:0
~/>
```